# Transition from one forced-directed graph to another graph in d3js

Tags: d3.js, tree, transition, force-layout

I have two Collapsible Force Trees for same nodes.

I haven't seen an example that we can transit from one tree to another with nodes transition and edges reconstruction in d3js.

Is there any way to do that?

Another relevant question, could we initialize the position of each node for forced-directed graph?

EDIT: Here is an [example](http://ec2-54-213-62-166.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081/). I have two trees, the link is one, and I have another tree with same molecules but different tree structure. I am thinking it will be nice if I can animate between different trees for same molecules or entities.

Comment: What do you mean by *distance function*? do you mean `linkDistance` or are you referring to some calculation you're performing in the `tick` function?

Comment: @t.888, sorry for the confusion, the distance function is the way I get linkDistance and tree structure, but I feel linkDistance is not very distinct in force directed graph.

Comment: You can set `x` and `y` properties on the nodes to initialize their position prior to handing the nodes array to the force layout, but I've had problems when setting multiple nodes to the same position - it makes the graph go crazy.

Comment: If the only difference between your two force layouts is the function you're using to evaluate linkDistance, then you can just swap the function out for another one in a single layout.

Comment: @t.888 two tree structures are very different. So, edge reconstruction transition is needed, basically two json files.

Comment: That could be tricky. You could possibly do a custom transition in the tick function, by considering the difference between the old positions and the new ones as vectors, then pushing your line points along those vectors over time.

Comment: It sounds like it would be a standard transition. It would help if you could post a concrete example.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Here is an [example](http://ec2-54-213-62-166.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080). I have two trees, the link is one, and I have another tree with same molecules but different tree structure. I am thinking it will be nice if I can animate between different trees for same molecules or entities.

Comment: Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/8425194) as proof of concept?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, That's almost half way. If the initial position of second network could be pre-calculated stable position, but not random positions, the problem will be solved.

Comment: I guess you could have a second force layout in the "background" that initialises the other graph. Do you have an example with two such graphs that you would want to transition?

Comment: @user2149631, a stable force layout is essentially a precalculation of node positions; you would just need to extract the x and y values of the nodes from a stable layout and feed those same values to the nodes you want to precalculate. It's a bit clumsy but it would probably work.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Please check files[1](http://ec2-54-213-62-166.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/test.json.1),[2](http://ec2-54-213-62-166.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/test.json), For tree, intermediate nodes does not matter. So, transition is only applied to leaf nodes. You may find inconsistent between the number of intermediate nodes of two trees.

Comment: @t.888, I am thinking about using Yifan Hu's layout program sdtp to get a svg file on server, and then read by d3, and updates links and nodes. Feel not very practical, as node identity will be lost..

Comment: Your JSON is hierarchical -- how do you put that into the force layout?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Follow the example from [here](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html)

Comment: Right, something like [this](https://vida.io/documents/Aea4ZgQZ88Fx6AZMu)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff could you update files with [1](http://ec2-54-213-62-166.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/test.json.a), [2](http://ec2-54-213-62-166.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/test.json.t)? I saw inconsistency between two trees. Looks like you don't really use var force1, just update links.

Comment: Updated -- https://vida.io/documents/Aea4ZgQZ88Fx6AZMu

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Is that possible for intermediate nodes to appear after leafs, and not from top left corner, but from where they were?

Comment: Ok, I think we're getting some feature creep here. I can't really give you a full solution, especially if you come up with new requests every time I update. I do believe that the example I've posted should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll add this as an answer then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In principle, these are the steps to follow.

- Stop the force layout to freeze the positions of the nodes.
- Disappear the links (e.g. fade out).
- Transition the nodes to their new positions. This can be done by setting the new positions on the old data or changing the data completely and then using the same code as in the `tick` handler for a force layout with a transition
- Re-add the links.
- If the new layout also uses a force layout, start that.

I've implemented an example of this [here](https://vida.io/documents/Aea4ZgQZ88Fx6AZMu). I uses two sets of data and two force layouts. At first, only the nodes and links of the first force layout are displayed and the second only runs in the background. Then, the first is stopped and I follow the steps outlined above.

This isn't going to satisfy all requirements (e.g. with respect to how nodes should transition), but can be used as a starting point for such an implementation.

Comment: ...and it would be really helpful if the person who downvoted could explain how this answer isn't helpful.

Comment: I have a question: when updating links and nodes positions, does the tick function of force0 need to be changed to null?

Comment: No. It won't be called if the force layout is stopped.