# How to change the data in a force layout graph dynamically ? D3

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js

I have a few JSON files I can use with my force directed graph and I wish to choose which one I run.
I can just change the name of what JSON is read in the HTML file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="networkA.json"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="networkB.json"></script>
```

but I wish to do this dynamically.

So when I first load the SVG my choice of data pops up and I get to choose which one I want the force directed graph to run off.

Also, wish to change this when its running, but knowing how to do the start up will probably answer that question.

Here is a perfect demo that can change dynamically:

'http://projects.flowingdata.com/tut/interactive_network_demo/'

but I wish to do something similar on a force directed graph

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122811/transition-from-one-forced-directed-graph-to-another-graph-in-d3js) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use d3.json to load the data dynamically based on UI selection, as documented here:

```
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests
```